# Generalize the text style as Class?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to generalize textstyle and make some class `class MyText` as follows.
Basically, I want to use the style defined in `MyText(){}` and when it will be minorly　changed, I can use the Class like MyText(myFontSize:20.0).style().

1. Is this kind of class curious or unusual to write or maintain the code reasonably?
   Since I'm very new to the class and object-oriented programming I wonder if the code is correct, especially in case 'Most parts are Used commomly' but 'Some parts are expected to be changed minorly'.
2. Based on #1, is the way of Initializing in `myText(){//here}` appropriate, even though it works without errors?

```
//main.dart
                Container(
                    child: Text(
                      "example",
                      style: MyText().style()
                    ),
                  ),
                ),

//style.dart
class MyText{
  Color? myColor;
  FontWeight? myWeight;
  String? myFontFamily;
  double? myLetterSpacing;
  double? myFontSize;

  MyText({this.myColor,this.myWeight,this.myFontFamily,this.myLetterSpacing,this.myFontSize}){
    myColor == null ? myColor = const Color.fromARGB(255, 102, 102, 102):0;
    myWeight == null ? myWeight = FontWeight.w600:0;
    myFontFamily == null ? myFontFamily = 'KiwiMaru':0;
    myLetterSpacing == null ? myLetterSpacing = 0.5:0;
    myFontSize == null ? myFontSize = 14.0:0;
  }


    TextStyle style() {
    return TextStyle(
      color: myColor,
      fontWeight: myWeight,
      fontFamily: myFontFamily,
      letterSpacing:myLetterSpacing,
      fontSize: myFontSize,
    );
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another good practice would be creating a *constants.dart* file and defining a **TextStyle** variable to later use in all of your **Text** widgets;

**lib/constants.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

TextStyle kBodyText = const TextStyle(
  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
  color: Colors.red,
  fontSize: 50,
);
```

**lib/home.dart**

```
import 'constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  const Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Text located in the center of your application with custom style.',
          style: kBodyText,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your helpful comment.
However, If in case that the property "fontsize" should be changed like  `fontSize: 100` but others are same , how can I use the variable showen above ?

Comment: You can use the **.copyWith()** method like `kBodyText.copyWith(fontSize: 100)` for specific local changes.

Comment: what a amazing method it is....! thanks again!